# SVG: access defs item in HTML when SVG inside Object?

Tags: object, svg

Suppose I have an SVG which has the following defs:

```
<svg width="179" height="170" viewBox="0 0 179 170" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>Star 1</title>
    <defs>
        <g id="shape">
            <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
        </g>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path stroke="#979797" fill="#D8D8D8" d="M89.5 140.25l-54.958 28.893 10.496-61.196L.576 64.607l61.445-8.93L89.5 0l27.48 55.678 61.444 8.93-44.462 43.34 10.496 61.195z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

I am including that SVG inside an HTML document using the object tag. For example:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="star.svg" class="svgObjectWrapper">
  Your browser doesn't support SVG
</object>
```

Is there any way, in the HTML document, to reference/use those defs from the SVG (which is in turn inside the object). For example, this doesn't seem to work. Should this be possible?

```
<use xlink:href="#shape" x="50" y="50" />
```

My guess is no, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since <object> loads the svg in a separate document you can't use local references (such as `<use xlink:href="#shape"/>`) in the top document to reach resources inside the other document. It is possible to reference external resources with <use> though, e.g `<use xlink:href="star.svg#shape"/>`. Note that this still does not mean that it's the same document as that in the <object>, e.g if you change elements inside the <object> element it will have no effect on `<use xlink:href="star.svg#shape"/>`.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks. One further clarification on that last point. Are you saying that if I use a reference to the def like this: `<use xlink:href="star.svg#shape" x="50" y="50" />`  to place that shape in the HTML, and then, via script, amend that #shape (the one inside the Object) via script, the inserted #shape (the one placed on the page with <use>) will not update with the change? That would make sense, just wanted to be certain I have it right!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible on UAs that support it (Firefox does for instance) and you don't even need an object tag if all you want is to reference a document via `<use>`.

Per the SVG specification you can just put in the URL of the file you want to use the data from i.e.

```
<use xlink:href="star.svg#shape" x="50" y="50" />
```

star.svg has to be on the same domain as your html file.

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm aware of that. However, I'm specifically interested in whether this should be possible with the SVG inside an object tag.

Comment: No, as per my answer there would be no reason to support that.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I mis-read your answer originally and missed the amended href.